# Is there a way to gracefully fail when an external package is not available and still run domReady?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm creating a share bar widget in Dojo 1.7.2 and conditionally loading the external social media APIs as packages using `require()` as follows:

```
require({
    packages:[
        {name: "twitter-api", location: "https://platform.twitter.com", main: "widgets"}
    ]
},["twitter-api"], lang.hitch(this, function(){
    // Do some social stuff with twitter API
}));
```

This works great whenever I can reach the Twitter API, but now that I'm testing this over a private network, I can't.  The problem isn't that the widget won't work though.  Instead, I have some additional code that runs from within a `ready()`, same for a `domReady()`, call after this bit of package loading tried and fails to load.

I did some digging on the Dojo documentation to figure out why my ready wasn't firing and ran across this reasoning ([domReady](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html#sync-loader)):

> Now comes along dojo/domReady!. The loader loads all the dependencies
>   for dojo/domReady! and then demands the plugin resource be resolved.
>   But dojo/domReady! may not be able to resolve the demanded plugin
>   resource (an empty module ID which is intended to signal the DOM is
>   ready) because the DOM may not be ready. The loader notices this an
>   sees that the module was not capable of being loaded synchronously,
>   gives up and continues.
>
> This is an intentional limitation in the loader, since handling it
>   would have required more complicated code. It will cease to be an
>   issue for Dojo 2.0, when the synchronous loader is desupported.

From what I am gathering, Dojo just stops trying whenever a dependency can't be loaded.  That's fine, but is there **any** way to gracefully handle a situation where an external library is unavailable?

I thought that maybe there might be some way to do it with an XHR call, but that leads to Cross-origin problems.  My only other solution is to just add them as separate script tags which is how a few other libraries are being loaded; but since this module is being refactored right now, I wanted to try and make it as AMD compliant as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stafamus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28078791/691711) is a really close solution to resolving the issue at hand.  Effectively, since you can't be sure that the `require` will ever finish, you can't try to resolve or reject a promise in it.  I ended up using a [`dojo/Deferred`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/Deferred.html) in conjunction with [`dojo.io.script`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/io/script.html) in order to have the Twitter API load asynchronously and then resolve the promise from within the callback that the Twitter API calls whenever it is loaded.

Also remember that I am using **Dojo 1.7.2**.  Beginning with **Dojo 1.8**, `dojo.io.script` is deprecated in favor of [`dojo/request/script`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/script.html).  I have not looked into the difference between the two.

This code could probably be optimized a little better, for example I don't think that you need to use a `declare` or if you do you could create a base API class, and I'm not sure that it works super well if you try to use or load the Twitter API more than once on a page.  However, it has fit my needs and I have adapted this solution to also load the Youtube, Google, and Facebook APIs in a similar fashion.

## Twitter.js

Basically the code boils down to using the `dojo.io.script` to have Dojo put a `<script>` tag with the Twitter src on the page which gets us the global that Twitter uses, `twttr` and tries to make sure that it isn't doing this if it doesn't need to.  Twitter has a "ready" callback that gets defined through `t.ready()` which we resolve our API promise in with a reference to the `twttr` global.  Really it's a Dojo wrapped way [Twitter tells you to do](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading) to load the JavaScript API already.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/Deferred",
    "dojo/io/script"
], function (
        declare,
        Deferred,
        ioScript
        ) {

    /**
     * @class api/Twitter
     * @classdesc Wrapper for the Twitter API which isn't inherently AMD
     */
    var Twitter = declare("api.Twitter", [], {
        /**
         * The deferred that we use to get a handle to API
         * @member {dojo/Deferred} api/Twitter#apiDeferred
         */
        apiDeferred: null,
        /**
         * The constructor which loads the API and starts the player creation
         * @method api/Twitter#constructor
         * @param {HTMLElement} container The id of the element to hold the player
         */
        constructor: function (container) {
            // Create a deferred that will resolve when we have a player
            this.apiDeferred = this.loadAPI();
        },
        /**
         * Function that loads the API from Twitter asynchronously
         * @method api/Twitter#loadAPI
         * @return {dojo/Deferred} The deferred that will resolve when the API is loaded
         */
        loadAPI: function () {

            // Create an API deferred to resolve when the API is loaded
            var apiDeferred = new Deferred();

            // Make sure that we haven't already loaded the Twitter API
            if (typeof twttr === "undefined") {

                /*
                 * This is where we wrap up the normally "synchronous" loading
                 * of whatever API we're using.  Twitter is slightly asynchronous
                 * in that it loads itself through creating a script tag and setting 
                 * the src which we can do with dojo.io.script already.  However,
                 * twitter expects there to exist a "twttr" variable whenever it loads
                 * much like dojo expects a dojoConfig.  In the twttr, there is an array
                 * of callbacks _e that will be called once the API is loaded.  This is
                 * where we create the boilerplate for Twitter. 
                 */

                // Create the twttr object from an immediately executed functor
                window.twttr = (function () {
                    // Make sure we don't already have a twttr object
                    var t = window.twttr || {};
                    // Create a ready callback array
                    t._e = [];
                    // Create a wrapper to allow pushing to the ready array
                    t.ready = function (f) {
                        t._e.push(f);
                    };
                    // Add our on callback that will let us know twitter loaded
                    t.ready(function (e) {
                        // Deliver the API through the deferred
                        apiDeferred.resolve(e.widgets);
                    });
                    // Return the twitter object
                    return t;
                }());

                // Ask dojo to load a new script tag with the Twitter API as the src
                ioScript.get({
                    url: "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js",
                    error: function (e) {
                        apiDeferred.reject("Twitter API seems incorrectly loaded.");
                    }
                });
            }
            // If we already have the Twitter API, we can resolve right now
            else {
                if (typeof twttr.widgets !== "undefined") {
                    apiDeferred.resolve(twttr.widgets);
                }
                else {
                    apiDeferred.reject("Twitter API seems incorrectly loaded.");
                }
            }

            // Return the API Deferred
            return apiDeferred;
        },
        /**
         * Function to get a handle to the deferred that should resolve to the twitter API
         * @member api/Twitter#getAPIDeferred
         * @returns {dojo/Deferred} The Twitter API
         */
        getAPIDeferred: function () {
            return this.apiDeferred;
        }
    });

    // Return our class
    return Twitter;
});
```

## ShareBar.js

In my widget, I have switches to let me disable Social API's and if I want to use one, I just require the wrapped API above.  Then I make a new `Twitter`, ask for the API Deferred, and if it resolves, I create the Twitter buttons.  This file is severely truncated and does not include all the widget code, only the actual using of the API code.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "Twitter"
], function (
        declare,
        Twitter
        ) {
    /**
     * @class ShareBar
     * @classdesc Widget used to display social media functionality on a page.
     */
    var ShareBar = declare({
        /**
         * By requiring the Twitter API, we have the twttr JS 
         * object which we can use to do Twitter stuff like 
         * parsing tweet buttons
         * @method ShareBar#_loadTwitter
         */
        _loadTwitter: function () {
            var
                    // Create a twitter module
                    twitter = new Twitter(),
                    // Get a closure safe handle to our twitter button
                    twitterButton = this.TwitterButton,
                    // Create a callback for when the twitter API loads
                    twitterSuccess = function (twitterAPI) {
                        // Run the twitter parser on our twitter button
                        twitterAPI.load(twitterButton);
                        // Allow the twitter button to be seen
                        domClass.remove(twitterButton, "hiddenSocialButton");
                    },
                    // Create an errback for if the twitter API fails
                    twitterFail = function (err) {
                        // Note the error
                        console.log(err);
                    };
            // Wait for the API to resolve and use the callbacks
            twitter.getAPIDeferred().then(twitterSuccess, twitterFail);
        }
    });

    // Return widget
    return ShareBar;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a promise and resolve it when require is successful; and fail gracefully at promise's error handler:

```
require(["dojo/Deferred"], function(Deferred){
    var d = new Deferred();
    require(['twitter-api'], function(twitterApi){
        d.resolve(twitterApi);
    });
    d.then(function(api){
        // use api
    }, function(err){
        // fail gracefully
    });
    return d.promise;
});
```

Comment: Your error callback will never actually get reached with this code, since nothing ever tells the deferred to reject.  Rejecting appropriately is a challenge or fudge at best, since your choices are basically to either set up a timeout, or attempt to use the dojo loader's events API which can tell you when a module load fails, but you could end up also receiving events for modules you aren't interested in.

Comment: thanks Ken. @zero298, it is a difficult problem and Ken's suggestions here are way to go.

Comment: Thanks @stafamus this is effectively how I resolved the issue in conjunction with [dojo.io.script](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/io/script.html)  Except I depend on the regular API ready callback to resolve the promise.  I will try to post a full implementation example when I get time.